# Eclipse: I can't find Java Build Path in Project Properties

Tags: java, eclipse, file

As the question states, I can't find the Java build path within the project properties itself

[image: Photo of my question]

My main issue is that I keep getting "The Class file is not on the classpath" error whenever I try to open a .class file from a school project. To fix this I need to access the Java build path within project properties but it is not showing up for me. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Mac, but i guess You should try this if you haven't done it yet.

File-Import-Existing_project into the workspace. Browse to the location where the .classpath and .project files locates in your project.

Then check your environment variables (google can help with this) and classpath variables:
Window - Preferences - Java - Build Path - Classpath Variables.

Answer (score 0):

The project seems like is a general project (No java project), so it's normal that 'Java build' option is missed.

Besides, you can't open .class files, because is a Java compiled file by the Java compiler. You must search for .java files.